# Unable to install MPlayer on ubuntu Linux 3.2.0-76-generic

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, xubuntu, mplayer

I am trying to install MPlayer on my Ubuntu system but every time I am getting following text on terminal:

"Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
0% [Connecting to 10.0.0.100 (10.0.0.100)]"

Otherway round i tried from Ubuntu software center and it everytime show the warning "The action would require the installation of packages from not authenticated sources." I am confused what to do?

Please suggest me a way so that i can install it properly on my system.
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added a repository to your system, but you did not have registered the GPG-key.

You can do the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager
```

Start the programm "Y PPA Manager"

[image]

Click *Advanced*

[image]

Click *Try to import all missing GPG keys*

And just wait until the import completed.

Then:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: @chetan Were you satisfied with my answer? Then give me a upvote (∧). If I could solve your problem, then it would be nice if you'd mark my answer (✓). ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I am trying to upvote but it requires 15 reputation which i currently don't have. i will do it asap. thanks once again.

Comment: Does y-ppa-manager work under unity?

Comment: @Fabby sure, tested in an earlier installation with Unity as GUI. Currently I'm using GNOME. Therefore the GNOME screenshots.